# any feature on linux like Perfermance Counter on Windows servers?

Tags: java, tomcat, centos

I have a tomcat web application, when invoking an unstable remote API, I want to get realtime http request time at any time. On windows server, I can use Performance Counter, does centos provide someone like that?

Comment: Dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1100733/concept-of-performance-counters-in-linux-unix  ?

Answer (score 2):

You should look into monitoring your host through monitoring software. I recommend Zabbix as it's very easy to set up: [www.zabbix.com](http://www.zabbix.com/)

You could try munin as well if this is for one host only: [http://munin-monitoring.org](http://munin-monitoring.org/)

That will give you much needed graphs and storage for your monitoring data. Then you can play with - for example - `ab` - apache benchmark http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/programs/ab.html

Comment: I second that. For monitoring zabbix is by far the best solution. Imo it's even superior to what the tools around performance counters in windows provide you with. That's why I monitor windows and linux systems alike with zabbix. In some cases I just pass the performance counters to zabbix to visualize them, in other cases I gather information which aren't available via performance counters.

Answer (score 0):

For Linux, 'Perf' subsystem is there to assist in such cases.

For HTTP request time details, please use httperf. Below link is for reference. http://linux.die.net/man/1/httperf

Answer (score 0):

I usually use Apache Top; you can find it here : http://www.fr3nd.net/projects/apache-top/

Answer (score 0):

If you use linux, you can install apache-benchmark ( http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/programs/ab.html )

It's more powerful as stress test.

Zabbix and other SNMP tool are useful as monitoring tools, not stress-tester.